# Protractor: stop do while loop once element is found

Tags: javascript, loops, protractor, element

In non-Angular page using Protractor I have a situation where I have to loop trough some list of elements on the page and once I find the element I'm looking for, I have to stop the loop and click on that element.

Page object file:

```
var homePage = function() {
    this.elementLists = browser.element(by.id('list')).all(by.css('div.list'));
    this.elementLink = browser.element(by.id('list')).element(by.css('div[data-code="GAA"]'));
    this.paginationRight = browser.element(by.css('.navi-right'));
    ...
}
module.exports = homePage;
```

Spec file:

```
// page objects
var homePage = require('../home_page/home_page.js');

// variables
var maxLoopCount = '';
var i = 0;

describe(...
    it(...
        // initialize page object
        var home = new homePage();

        // store number of listsinto a variable
        home.elementLists.count().then(function(num) {
            maxLoopCount = num;

            // click on right paginator arrow until element is displayed in the list
            while (i < maxLoopCount) {
                home.paginationRight.click();
                browser.sleep(1500);
                if (expect(home.elementLink.isPresent()).toBeTruthy()) {
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            };
    });
});
```

I know I should use `if (elementFound === true)`, but how can I do that?

Comment: So basically if you achieve `GAA`, you need to move out. M i right?

Comment: Yes, and below answer form Chuck Brown is the right thing which solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest something a little more recursive.
protractor.expectedCondition is also a gold mind when waiting for things to happen

```
// page objects
var homePage = require('../home_page/home_page.js');

// variables
var maxLoopCount = '';
var i = 0;

describe(...
  it(...
    // initialize page object
    var home = new homePage();

    // store number of listsinto a variable
    home.elementLists.count().then(function(num) {
        maxLoopCount = num;

        // click on right paginator arrow until element is displayed in the list
        nextPageAndCheck(1, maxLoopCount);
    });
 }); 

nextPageAndCheck = function(page, pageCount) {
  if(page <= pageCount) {
    home.paginationRight.click();
    browser.wait(protractor.expectedCondition.visibilityOf(home.elementLink),1500, "not on this page").then(
       function(passed){return passed}, 
       function(error) {
          nextPageAndCheck(page++, pageCount);
       })
  } else {
       throw("couldn't find it error")
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'isDisplayed() or isPresent()' according to your need,  something like this:

```
home.elementLists.each(function(elem){
 home.paginationRight.click();
 home.elementLink.isDisplayed().then(function(value){
  if(value === true){
     break;
   }else {
     console.log("element not visible");
    }
 });     
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me as it returns an error ** break; ^^^^^ SyntaxError: Illegal break statement**. Break is correctly used in the if statement in the curved brackets `if(value === true) { break; }`, but the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf($('.page-list-content')), 6000);
```

Comment: Can't use it as element is not visible on the page, that is why I have to click on paginationRight arrow element until I can see it.